# Calculate total days from two dates in python openerp

Tags: python, openerp-7

I have three fields `start_date`, `end_date` and `total_days`.

If i enter `start_date` and `end_date` field it should automatically display `total_days`.

This is my Function which is not working.

```
<field name="start_date" on_change="get_number_of_days(start_date,end_date)"/>
<field name="end_date" on_change="get_number_of_days(end_date,start_date)"/>
<field name="total_days" />

def get_number_of_days(self, cr, uid, ids, start_date, end_date):
        """Returns a float equals to the timedelta between two dates given as string."""
        result = self.browse(cr, uid, ids)
        if (end_date and start_date) and (start_date <= end_date):
            DATETIME_FORMAT = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"
            from_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(start_date, DATETIME_FORMAT)
            to_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(end_date, DATETIME_FORMAT)
            timedelta = to_dt - from_dt
            diff_day = timedelta.days + float(timedelta.seconds) / 86400
            result['value']['total_days'] = round(math.floor(diff_day))+1
        return result
```

Is there any other method? or what may be the issue

Comment: please provide information of what's wrong, it would simplify error lookup

Comment: it is not giving any error. just it is saving without calculating. I could not trace where it went wrong

Comment: Sounds as if your conditional never evaluates to ``True`` and the result always remains the same as provided by ``self.browse(...)``.

Answer (score 2):

The section:

```
        diff_day = timedelta.days + float(timedelta.seconds) / 86400
        result['value']['total_days'] = round(math.floor(diff_day))+1
```

is largely unnecessary as `datetime.timedelta` already has the number of whole days as a value `timedelta.days` - I suspect that your problem is that you are not converting to a string try:

```
         result['value']['total_days'] = str(timedelta.days)
```

You should also consider catching problems when the `strptime` function cannot convert the current value, e.g. when it is blank.

Answer (score 2):

If your dates are given as strings (as your docstring says), the second part of your conditional may behave unexpectedly (depending on the date/time formatting), because you perform a lexicographical comparison:

```
if (end_date and start_date) and (start_date <= end_date):
    # ...
```

You should convert them to datetime-objects **first** and then check your conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You,

I wrote new function for this which helped to give total days:

```
def _get_days(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg ,context=None):
        res = {}
        fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
        for object in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            res[object.id] = {'total_days':0, } 
            from_date = object.start_date 
            to_date = object.end_date
            d1 = datetime.strptime(from_date, fmt)
            d2 = datetime.strptime(to_date, fmt)
            daysDiff = str((d2-d1).days+1)
            res[object.id]['total_days'] = daysDiff
            return res

'start_date': fields.date('Start Date', required=True),
        'end_date': fields.date('End Date', required=True),
        'total_days': fields.function(_get_days, string="Diff days", multi='sums', store=True),
```